# How to compute the angles between 2 vectors, to proceed to a rotation?

Tags: c#, opengl, math, unity-game-engine, directx

I have 2 vectors with the same origin, and I would simply like to rotate one to match the other. However, I just can't find the math to be able to compute the x angle, the y angle and the z angle (World coordinates) between the two. 
It would also work to get this angles in Local coordinates, I don't know if it helps but the rotation around the Forward vector (Local Y) can be anything it doesn't matter. I only need my object to be facing the right direction.

How could I do ?

Comment: `angle = Math.Acos((x1*x2+y1*y2+z1*z2) / Math.Sqrt(x1*x1+y1*y1+z1*z1)/Math.Sqrt(x2*x2+y2*y2+z2*z2))`?

Comment: this is the angle between the two right ? I would need the xAngle, the yAngle and the zAngle to proceed to the rotation

Comment: Well, you have to *define* what `xAngle` is; if it's an angle between `(1, 0, 0)` vector and given one, `xAngle = Math.Acos(x1 / Math.Sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1* y1 + z1 * z1))`; the difference (how much you have to rotate) `xAngleDelta = Math.Acos(x1 / Math.Sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1* y1 + z1 * z1)) - Math.Acos(x2 / Math.Sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2* y2 + z2 * z2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. Let me first suggest the **cross product**, as it is easier to understand than most alternatives (like Quaternions) and might Point you in the right direction.

Basically the cross product between two vectors (`a` and `b`) results in a third vector (`c`)which is perpendicular to both. It is also interesting to note, that the length of this third vector is exactly `length(a)*length(b)*sin(Theta)`, where Theta is the angle between `a` and `b`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
c.x = a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y
c.y = a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z
c.z = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x
```

A very simple formula.

Now the trick is, to normalize `a` and `b`. Which means to set their length to 1. This is done by taking the vector and dividing each component by it's length

```
length_a = sqrt(a_old.x * a_old.x + a_old.y * a_old.y + a_old.z * a_old.z)
a.x = a_old.x / length_a
a.y = a_old.y / length_a
a.z = a_old.z / length_a
```

Using both normalized vectors as Input for the cross product will result in `c`'s length being `1 * 1 * sin(Theta)` or just `sin(Theta)`.

(As an alternative, you can also do this with a **dot product**, as Dmitry Bychenko pointed out in the comments)

What can you do next? You can now freely rotate either `a` or `b` around vector `c` using a [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). Do note however, that you would need to normalize `c` again to do this.